# VB.Net PasteSpecial Error Excel Office 365

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to paste huge data set from one source to another. It was working fine. Suddenly it start throwing the below error. Please advise.

This drives me crazy...

```vb
    Dim CR As Range = xlsSheet.Range(position)
    xlsSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, False, False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, True)
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()
```

I'm getting below error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException HResult=0x800A03EC
>   Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Source=ExcelLib StackTrace:
>   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.PasteSpecial(Object
>   Format, Object Link, Object DisplayAsIcon, Object IconFileName, Object
>   IconIndex, Object IconLabel, Object NoHTMLFormatting

Comment: I'm getting below error:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x800A03EC
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
  Source=ExcelLib
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.PasteSpecial(Object Format, Object Link, Object DisplayAsIcon, Object IconFileName, Object IconIndex, Object IconLabel, Object NoHTMLFormatting)

Comment: Have you confirmed that `CR` is a valid range?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to overcome the above error.

- Restart your excel
- Change your code as mentioned below:

> Code

`Dim ws1 As Worksheet`
`Dim ws2 As Worksheet`
`Dim copyRange As Range`
`Dim destRange As Range`
`ws1 = xlsWB.Sheets(srcSheet)`
`ws2 = xlsWB.Sheets(destSheet)`
`copyRange = ws1.Range(srcRange)`
`destRange = ws2.Range(position)`
`GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`
`ws2.Select()`
`copyRange.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Copy(Destination:=destRange)`
`GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()`
`ws1 = Nothing`
`ws2 = Nothing`